# Is there a function to check if a timer is running in Java?

Tags: java, game-physics

I am writing a program where i want to change certain values if the timer is not running, I am wondering if there is any function/keyword used to see if the timer is still active like if(timer.isActive) etc in the java.util.Timer package

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I dont have any i was asking the question of is it possible

Comment: Just use a boolean variable to keep track of when the timer was started and stopped. You can start the timer using `Timer.schedule` and stop the timer using `Timer.cancel`.